# Why the IDE doesn't recognize my input?

Tags: c++, ide, clion

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hello, World!";

    return 0;
}
```

ALL instruction/text I insert become grey... I just installed **CLion**, maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: #include <curses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

specifically these instructions become grey...

Comment: You should contact the product vendor and / or read the product documentation.

Comment: Could it be syntax highlighting?

Comment: Thinking like an IDE, does using #include "curses.h" and #include "stdlib.h" show the same behaviour?

Comment: Have you checked the file name? is it cpp?

Comment: @Stefan yup, i also checked if i have clang and i have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLion greys out includes that aren't used in your code.
`std::cout` is from iostream (which isn't greyed out)

Try Building `Ctrl + F9` and debugging `Shift + F9` your code, you'll see your outputs

`Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Process finished with exit code 0`

Comment: When using the corresponding implementations from curses you'll see that it isn't greyed out.